# Connect to ActiveMQ using erlang RabbitMQ client

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, activemq-classic

I am trying to connect to the ActiveMQ server using RabbitMQ erlang client.

```
URI = "amqp://server:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600",
{ok,ConnParams} = amqp_uri:parse(URI),
amqp_connection:start(ConnParams).
```

And getting an error message:

```
{error,{socket_closed_unexpectedly,'connection.start'}}
```

According to the ActiveMQ documentation, it is supported AMQP protocol version 1.0.

RabbitMQ  AMQP protocol version is 0.9

Are there any way to establish connection to the ActiveMQ from RabbitMQ erlang client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, ActiveMQ only understands AMQP v1.0 as that is an OASIS standard, the earlier AMQP versions will not be supported.  You can use STOMP, AMQP, MQTT or native OpenWire client's to talk to ActiveMQ so you have plenty of options.